# Grayscale/Brightness Resolution vs Contrast

Tags: computer-vision, image-processing, resolution

A bit of noob question, but can't find a definite answer anywhere:

What is the difference between **Gray-scale resolution** of an image and the **Image contrast**.
Are they different terminology for the same thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gray-scale resolution and image contrast are different.

[Gray-scale resolution](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/962727) looks at *how many* gray scales are being used to present the image.

[Image contrast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contrast_(vision)), on the other hand, looks at the difference between the maximum and minimum values of the gray scales used to present an image.

For example, a low gray-scale resolution, low contrast image might only use #000000 and #010101 (#RRGGBB where RR = red value, GG = green value, BB = blue value).

A low gray-scale resolution, **high** contrast image might only use #000000 and #FFFFFF (and only those two gray-scale values).

A **high** gray-scale resolution, low contrast image might have a maximum gray scale value of #1F1F1F (5 bits) and a minimum of #000000, but use all gray scales in between.

A **high** gray-scale resolution, **high** contrast image might have a maximum gray scale value of #FFFFFF (8 bits) and a minimum of #000000 (and use all gray scales in between).